# Search for factors of integers and how many of them

Tags: excel, vba

I have a homework to make a program using the VBA in excel (using the Command Button (ActiveX Control). I need to make a code to show how many factors are there and what are the factors of an integer.

I'm a total beginner. I only know how to use "For... to..." and "If... then..." just a few hours ago.
I knew if I want to search for the factors then n as the integer we input and i as number from 1 to n.

```
If n mod i = 0 then 
  //all the i are the factors.
```

I don't know how to write it in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction

```
Sub factors()
N = Range("A1").Value ' number in cell A1
r = 1
For i = 1 To N - 1
  If N Mod i = 0 Then
    Cells(r, 2) = i
    r = r + 1
  End If
Next
End Sub
```